# Special characters in column name

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I've a oledb select query which retrieves data from a column having special character `/`.

How to get rid of this as I can't change the column name in Excel?

If I try to remove the `/`, then it works:

```
Select count (*) From [DashBoard$A2:A100] WHERE [Mono/Multicube] LIKE 'UAT%'
```

Comment: Try escaping it as Mono//Multicube

Comment: oledb Exception: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Mono//multicube LIKE 'UAT%''.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions to get OLEDB working in that case. If you're not set on using OLEDB, you might consider using EPPlus to read the Excel data instead. It's open source and designed to be used in server environments. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Comment: Grave accent (backtick) made the favour. Thanks for the help Eric